# How do I adjust this code to access and display multiple object records in a singular Visualforce page table

Tags: apex, visualforce, custom-object, wrapper-class

I have a Visualforce page built by someone a long time ago, and I am trying to add a second object's records to a table that is already displaying correctly.  They have the same fields, but different custom objects (Product_consumed__c and Products_consumed_from_stock__c).  I can't do a dual record type simple solution because from stock is a master detail while regular consumed is not.  I am new to apex and VF so any guidance on how to adjust the following Apex and VF would be very helpful. Thank you!  Here is the desired output in a screenshot.
[image]

```
public class DownloadServicePDF{

public List<CaseComment> casecmtList{get;set;}
public Case caseIns{get;set;}
public string accountAddress{get;set;}
Public List<Service_Activity__c> taskList{get;set;}
Public List<Product_Consumed__c> prodList{get;set;}
public List<Products_consumed_from_stock__c> prodStockList{get;set;}
public string showTravelHours{get;set;}
public string showcmnt{get;set;}
public string showProdConsumed{get;set;}
public string workdetails{get;set;}

public DownloadServicePDF(){
    taskList = new List<Service_Activity__c>();
    Id caseRecId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('recId');
    showcmnt = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('comment');
    showTravelHours = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('labour');
    showProdConsumed = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('prodconsum');
    
    if(caseRecId != Null){
        
        caseIns= [SELECT Id,AccountId,AssetId,Subject,Scheduled_Date_Time__c,CaseNumber,Description,ClosedDate,CreatedDate,Account.Name,Account.ShippingStreet,
                  Account.ShippingState,Account.ShippingCity,Account.ShippingPostalCode,Account.BillingCountry,Type,Completed_Date_Time_Formula__c,
                  Account.Phone,Primary_Engineer__c,Primary_Engineer__r.Name,Secondary_Engineer__c,Secondary_Engineer__r.Name,Support_Member__c,Support_Member__r.Name,Service_Provider__c,
                  Engineer_ETA__c,Labor_Hours__c,Travel_Hours__c,Tech_Support_Hours__c,Asset.Name,Asset.Contact.Name,Asset.SerialNumber,Asset.RecordTypeId,Asset.RecordType.Name,Make_Model_Serial__c FROM case WHERE Id =: caseRecId];
        
        for(Service_Activity__c dbTask : [SELECT Id,Name,FSE_Comments__c,Service_Date__c,Case__c,Private__c,createdDate FROM Service_Activity__c WHERE Case__c =: caseRecId AND Private__c =: False ORDER BY Service_Date__c ASC]){
            workdetails = 'true';
            taskList.add(dbTask);
        }
        
        accountAddress = caseIns.Account.ShippingStreet+'\n'+caseIns.Account.ShippingCity+', '+caseIns.Account.ShippingState+' '+caseIns.Account.ShippingPostalCode+'\n'+'Ph: '+caseIns.Account.Phone;
        
        
        casecmtList = new List<CaseComment>(); 
        
        for(CaseComment dbcasecmnt : [select commentbody, createddate from CaseComment where parentid = : caseRecId  and ispublished = true ORDER BY CreatedDate ASC]){
            casecmtList.add(dbcasecmnt);
        }
        
        prodList = new List<Product_Consumed__c>(); 
        for(Product_Consumed__c dbprodconsum : [select Id,Case__c,Name,Part_Number__c,Quantity_Consumed__c from Product_Consumed__c where Case__c = : caseRecId ORDER BY CreatedDate ASC]){
            prodList.add(dbprodconsum);
        }
    }       
}
```

}
And this is the Visualforce PDF code

```
<apex:page controller="DownloadServicePDF" renderAs="pdf"   standardStylesheets="false" showHeader="false" applyHtmlTag="false" sidebar="false" docType="html-5.0">
```

REMOVED EXTRA LINES OF THE PDF OUTPUT FOR READABILITY - THIS IS THE SECTION THAT PRODUCES ONE TABLE WITH ONE OBJECT, BUT I NEED TO BE ABLE TO DISPLAY BOTH OBJECTS IN THE SAME TABLE

```
                  <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!showProdConsumed == 'true'}">
                    <br/>
                    <b style="font-size:100%;"> Products Consumed </b>
                    <apex:pageBlock >
                        <apex:dataTable value="{!prodList}" var="a" border="1"  styleClass="print-friendly" width="100%">
                            <apex:column styleClass="inBorder" >
                                <apex:facet name="header">Product Name</apex:facet>
                                <apex:outputText >{!a.Name}</apex:outputText>
                            </apex:column>       
                              <apex:column styleClass="inBorder" >
                                <apex:facet name="header">Part Number</apex:facet>
                                <apex:outputText >{!a.Part_Number__c}</apex:outputText>
                            </apex:column> 
                             <apex:column styleClass="inBorder" >
                                <apex:facet name="header">Quantity</apex:facet>
                                <apex:outputText >{!a.Quantity_Consumed__c}</apex:outputText>
                            </apex:column> 
                       </apex:dataTable>
                    </apex:pageBlock>
                </apex:outputPanel>
                 </div>
                 </div>
             </apex:form>
        </apex:page>
```

Comment: welcome to SFSE; please see [ask] on getting the most from the Community. I'd suggest using [edit] and put in a screen shot of the desired output. I suspect the general solution to this is to use a wrapper class in the VF controller and bind the VF page datatable to ta list of wrapper class objects rather than to a list of sobjects. But the screen shot of intended result is what we'll need

Comment: @cropredy I added a screenshot at the top of the output table.  Right now it only shows one objects records...but I would need a similar object (with same fields to output into the table when I generate a PDF using a visualforce button.) The button already works on the Case Object, and the only issue is the two objects joining.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the controller, create an inner class (in VF parlance, this is a wrapper class - it wraps multiple sobjects into an abstraction used by the VF page)

```
public class DownloadServicePDF{
 public class ProductConsumed {
   public String name {get; private set;}
   public String partNumber {get; pruvate set;}
   public Integer quantity {get; private set;}
   public ProductConsumed (Product_Consumed__c record) {
     this.name = record.name;
     this.partNumber = record.Part_Number__c;
     this.quantity = record.Quantity_Consumed__c;
   }
   public ProductConsumed (Products_Consumed_From_stock__crecord) {
     this.name = record.name;
     this.partNumber = record.Part_Number__c;
     this.quantity = record.Quantity_Consumed__c;
   }
 }

 // Then add a list of these inner class objects
 public ProductConsumed[] prodList = new List<ProductConsumed>();
 // Your other variables   
 public List<CaseComment> casecmtList{get;set;}
 ...

 public DownloadServicePDF(){
      ...
 // Then, populate this list of inner class (wrapper) objects from each SObject

   for(Product_Consumed__c productConsumed : [select Id,Case__c,Name,Part_Number__c,Quantity_Consumed__c from Product_Consumed__c where Case__c = : caseRecId ORDER BY CreatedDate ASC]){
        prodList.add(new ProductConsumed(productConsumed));
   }
   for (Product_Consumed_From_Stock__c productConsumedFromStock : {SELECT ..
       FROM Product_Consumed_From_Stock__c
       WHERE ...) {
         prodList.add(new ProductConsumed(productConsumedFromStock));
   }

 ...
 }
}
```

Now your VF page datatable still binds to the collection variable `prodList` but the three `outputText` are, respectively:

```
<apex:outputText >{!a.name}</apex:outputText>
<apex:outputText >{!a.partNumber}</apex:outputText>
<apex:outputText >{!a.quantity}</apex:outputText>
```

As an aside, the `dataTable` iteration variable should not be named `a` but rather `productConsumed`. I'd also rename the controller variable `prodList` to `productsConsumed` or better, `consumedProducts` (and change the corresponding `dataTable` binding.

Comment: one more question to clarify please...I understand what you are doing with these lines...but trying to fit your code and keep these classes isnt working for me...
Where would you fit all of this inside of the public class DownloadServicePDF?
I keep trying to figure out where to fit everything in similar locations while still maintaining the original class, and the public without argument DownloadServicePDF
Any more guidance would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: trying to fit your code and keep these classes is causing the classes and public statements to throw out invalid constructor names because ProductConsumed is conflicting with DownloadServicePDF class.

Comment: updated post to be clearer

Comment: thank you! I will test this out soon.  I am on a short deadline, so I have to release a less code heavy solution.  You have been a great help in teaching me and helping me! thank you!

Comment: I tested this and it works!  I moved a few items around and put the prodList in the lower public DownloadServicePDF section and it worked when generating the Visualforce PDF
Essentially I put public List<ProductConsumed> prodList{get;set;} in the top and then in the next public DownloadServicePDF I put prodList = new List<ProductConsumed>(); and it worked